# What are offline/client geometry capabilities of ArcGIS API for JavaScript?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, offline

Lately I've been going through ArcGIS JS API samples, but from what I've seen, it looks like all geometric functions always go through server, and use server side REST functions. There is no option to even calculate area of polygon using only JS API without server side funcions.

I have a case, where I have feature layer added from JSON file and I want to use some geometric functions un features inside. **Server connection is not an option, everything needs to be done on client side.**

Is there a way to do this with ArcGIS JavaScript API only, without using server side tasks or maybe some other alternative frameworks, that could use features from JSON file?

Comment: Can you list specifically what you'd like to do?

Comment: Right now I'm only looking for area/distance measurements and intersection area calculation. Also, finding all object intersections from feature layer would be nice. Identify or something like that could be useful also.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Checkout the [utility functions in the esri.geometry namespace](http://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jsapi/namespace_geometry.html). You can do areas and lengths client side with functions from there. You can also do point-in-polygon client side with [polygon.contains](http://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jsapi/polygon.html#contains) (also see [extent.contains](http://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jsapi/extent.html#contains)).

Comment: Thanks, thats what I needed. Are there also options for client-side idenfity function?

Comment: No client side identify (which is querying across multiple layers). You can do basic querying on a per-layer basis if your query filter is by object ID, an extent or by time. More complex where clause querying is not available purely client side.